# Haskell: What does the warning "Variable is implicitly quantified due to a context" mean?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

At this line

```
type SafeReturn a = Exception e => Either e a
```

I got this warning

```
Variable ‘e’ is implicitly quantified due to a context
Use explicit forall syntax instead.
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a free type variable in your type synonym which you haven't dealt with. To take the extreme example, if we removed your `a` parameter, we'd have something like

```
type SafeReturn = [e] -- Using a * -> * type instead of a * -> * -> * type
```

This probably isn't what you want since we don't know know exactly what `e` is referring to here and this is the same problem that your `SafeReturn` faces; what does the `e` mean?

Now there is one context where `e` could mean something and that's what the error message is telling you.

```
type SafeReturn a = forall e. Exception e => Either e a
```

This means something different. In fact you've created a universally quantified type here. This means that anything of type `SafeReturn a` has no way of inspecting `e` other than whatever methods are offered by `Exception`.

Comment: Actually, it is *not* an existential type; it's a universally quantified type, likely to appear in a higher-ranked position. The rest is correct. Existential types in Haskell are only ever created by `data` (or `data instance`) declarations; neither `type` nor `newtype` are sufficient.

Comment: The higher rank situation happens if you try to write a function that takes a `SafeReturn a` as an argument.